# Problemas ao enviar e-mail com função mail()

Tags: email, php

Estou tentando fazer o envio de e-mail, porem é retornado a mensagem de sucesso, mas a mensagem não é enviada.

Eu envio os dados do frontend para o backend com o Angular e os dados chegam direitinho, mas não sei o que ocorre que não envia.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");

$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$name      = $_POST['name'];
$email     = $_POST['email'];
$phone     = $_POST['phone'];
$place     = $_POST['place'];
$message   = $_POST['message'];


  $destino = "cliente@hotmail.com";

  $assunto = "Cliente.";

  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'From: $name <$email> '. "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Telefone: $phone '. "\r\n";
  //....

  $enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $headers);

  if($enviaremail)
  {
  echo 1;
  } 
  else 
  {
  echo 0;
  }
```

A hospedagem é o hostinger. Não sei se tem algo a ver.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações, pois costumamos mantê-las o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [Bate-papo do Stack Overflow em Português](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Comment: O código utiliza o e-mail do cliente como remetente (From), isso poderá ser um problema para o [DNS Reverso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#DNS_reverso), ou seja, basicamente o destinatário verifica se o IP do remetente é o mesmo IP do servidor de envio e então considera a mensagem como spam caso o IP não seja o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja o fato que tu está pulando um parâmetro:

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string
>   $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

Dá um confere no [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php).

Eu uso o código da seguinte forma (sem aqueles headers que tu utiliza, experimenta remover eles):

```
$name      = $_POST['name'];
$email     = $_POST['email']; 
$phone     = $_POST['phone'];
$place     = $_POST['place'];
$message   = $_POST['message'];

$m['subject'] = 'Qualquer Assunto'; 
$m['to'] = 'cliente@hotmail.com';

$m['message'] = '
E mail de contato:<br /><br />

Nome: '.$name.'<br />
E-mail: '.$email.'<br />
Telefone: '.$phone.'<br />
Localização: '.$place.'<br />
Mensagem: '.$message.'<br />

';

$m['headers'] = implode("\r\n",array(
                        'From: Contato <contato@dominiodocliente.com.br>',
                        'Reply-To: Contato <contato@seusite.com.br>',
                        'Subject: '.$m['subject'],
                        'Mime-Version: 1.0',
                        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',
                        'Priority: normal',
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion(),
                        'X-Priority: 3'));;

if(mail($m['to'],$m['subject'],$m['message'],$m['headers'])){   
    echo 'Seu contato foi enviado com sucesso.'; 
}
else echo 'Seu contato falhou.';
```

Comment: Thiago, vc diz o parâmetro $message?

$enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $message, $headers);?

Pq tbm fiz assim, e n está indo n.

Comment: Vou fazer o seguinte vou colocar um código PHP testado e funcionando aqui pra ti, daí tu só altera de acordo com tua necessidade, beleza?!

Comment: Pô Thiago, mt obgd por postar o código. Eu acho q ta acontecendo oq o amigo disse acima, pq estou testando com meu email da hotmail, tlvz só funcione msm com email do dominio do cliente.

Comment: Pois é, eu uso HostGator, na Hostinger pode haver alguma limitação, mas tu pode fazer exatamente o que o amigo comentou, vou atualizar o código para que tenha essa funcionalidade também!

Answer (score 0):

Um detalhe é que a função `mail()` retorna um `boolean` para a execução da função por assim dizer, e não se o email foi realmente enviado. A função foi executada corretamente, por isso vem `true`.

Quem relamente envia o email não é o PHP e sim algum outro software instalado no servidor, por isso o PHP não se responsabiliza por informar se o email realmente saiu do seu servidor (enviado).

Até por que o email na maioria dos casos acaba indo para uma fila, o que faz o seu email nao ser enviado imediatamente, mas será em um futuro próximo, se pensar por esse lado o retorno seria `false` o que levaria a varias complicações.

Em algumas hospedagens o `header` `from` tem que ser um email valido e existente do seu dominio, caso contrario não envia o email, ai adiciona o `reply-to` para o email que estava no `from`. Mais ou menos isso.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-to: $name <$email> '. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: email_existente@seudominio.com.br '. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Telefone: $phone '. "\r\n";
```

Comment: Vixe!! Então terei q pegar o e-mail do domínio do cliente, pq pro meu da hotmail n está sendo enviado d jeito maneiro. Valeu pena ajuda mano, vo pedir a ele, e posto o resultado aqui.

Comment: Há o problema do [DNS Reverso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#DNS_reverso), ou seja, basicamente o destinatário verifica se o IP do remetente é o mesmo IP do servidor de envio e então considera a mensagem como spam caso o IP não seja o mesmo.